# How do I convert from a tensorflow tensor to an image without using numpy?

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I was trying to use `numpy.asarray(tensor)` to convert a tensor into an ndarray. Then, I was planning to use PIL to convert that ndarray into a downloadable image. However, since I was running this code on a TPU, it got held up the numpy conversion and could not proceed to the PIL step. Is there any way to convert from a tensor to an image directly, without converting to an ndarray?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img` to convert a tensor to a `PIL` image:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = tf.random.normal((100, 100, 3))
pil_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(img)
plt.imshow(pil_img)
```

```
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f3483d71310>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out the real problem: after the graph was executed through the TPU, the output was in some sort of error state. I fixed it and then it started working better.